# When to use Jahren or Jahre?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

When we say how old we are we use 'jahre', i.e. 'Ich bin zwei Jahre alt.'
So when do we ever use 'Jahren'?

Comment: Did you consult any [grammar book/site](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? You should have found [dative plural](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jahr) there. What’s your actual question?

Answer (score 5):

You use "Jahren", when you put a preposition to it: "In zwei Jahren", "Nach fünf Jahren", "Vor neun Jahren". There is also an exception. When you talking about one year, you still use "Jahre": "In einem Jahr", "vor einem Jahr", "nach einem Jahr".

Comment: why does it change when its with a preposition though?

Comment: It's a grammar rule. 
"In fünf Jahre" sounds strange. 
"In fünf Jahren" sounds more comfortable. 
Some plural subjects ending with "e get also a "n"
One more example 
"Die Umstände" -> "Nach diesen Umständen".

Comment: You could also look up a declension table for "Jahr", like here: http://www.crodict.de/nomen/deutsch/Jahr.html

Comment: The preposition in requires dative, so you have to adjust the case accordingly.